# Azure DevOps create release

Tags: azure-devops

I've created a manual release defenition. I want to be able to create a new release and only have it containing new changes from the previous release that was deployed. Is this possible?

Comment: What type of "changes" are you talking about? Compiled code? Scripts? What problem are you trying to solve by doing this? Typically, releases should be idempotent and complete -- no release should rely on the results of a previous release.

Comment: If you mean deploying the latest version artifact which contains new changes. You can set the latest version as the artifact source in your release definition. If you mean only deploying the new changes, you can use copy files task to copy the new changes and deploy them.

Comment: We have about 25 different solutions all built into a different artifact. When creating a release I want the option of not deploying everything, just the artifakts that has changed since the last deployed release. Octopus for instance has this option as a simple switch and I wonder if there is a similar thing in azure devops.

Comment: Hi Did you get a chance to check out below answer? Please let me if it helped you to fix this issue

Answer (score 0):

If the 25 solutions are all built in a single build pipeline and published into a single artifact. You can add a script task in your build pipeline to check what solutions have been changed. And copy only the changed artifacts to publish. See below example in powershell script:

below inline script is just an example.

```
#get the folders that are changed
$folders = git diff --dirstat=files,0 HEAD~1 | Select-String '[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\% (.*)\/' | ForEach-Object{$_.Matches.Groups[1].Value}

#copy the the changed solution built result to artifact folder to publish
foreach ($folder in $folders){ Move-Item -Path $folder/bin  -Destination "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)"}
```

In above powershell task. The first line of script will get all the changed folders. The second line will move the built result of changed solution to artifact folder to be publised.

For your solutions might output the built results in a different place. You need to change the `-Path` parameter of `Move-Item` command accordingly. You might need to change the `-Destination` parameter too.

Then you can publish the `Destination` folder which only contains the changed artifacts via `publish build artifact task`. And then your release pipeline will only deploy the artifacts that have changed.

The main idea is to check which solution has changed and copy out the changed artifacts, and only publish them as the artifacts.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly (based on comments), and the 25 solutions are all artifacts that could contribute to a release, but you just want the one that triggered the release to be deployed, you could establish a condition on that job. With YAML, put a `condition` property on the job, and with classic releases, under Additional Options, choose "Custom condition using variable expressions", and then use a condition like

```
or(eq(variables['Release.TriggeringArtifact.Alias'], ''), eq(variables['Release.TriggeringArtifact.Alias'], 'MyArtifactName'))
```

The above example allows the deployment if the triggering artifact that created this release instance matches `MyArtifactName`, or if there was no triggering artifact (that is, a manual release creation).